# Fetch data before rendering components in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am using Vuejs with Vuex and I have actions that are used to fetch data from the database, I want the fetch to be before rendering the components depended on this data. So where can I put these actions in my code ?

Comment: you can use `created` or `mounted` hook for the fetch operation. Note that `created` is called before `mounted` hook.

Comment: @sazzad `mounted` runs each time we access the component and I think `created` too, so we will have repetition, how to avoid that ?

Comment: @Omar don't you want to fetch data whenever component enter?

Comment: `I have actions that are used to fetch data from the database` what does it mean ? Are you performing any action after page load to fetch the data ?

Comment: You can dispatch your actions inside the hooks `beforeRouteEnter` and/or `beforeRouteUpdate`.

Comment: @nosnart yes, I don't want the fetch to run whenever component enter, I want it to run only once when the application starts the first time.

Comment: @Omar It sounds unusual to me, logically need to fetch data from db every time enter page. If you want to do so you might need store a variable in browser storage to know that API has been fetched or not

Comment: @CreativeLearner  I want to dispatch my actions before the render of components and only once when the application starts the first time.

Comment: @nosnart I have a large database, for this I want to fetch some tables only once. I have a copy of this data in my store.

Answer (score 5):

You can use your action (ex: getData) on onMounted hook
and you can use async await to be sure that your action call is done before moving to the next step

here is an exemple (i used axios just for the exemple you are free to use any methode to get your data) :

```
<template>
  <h1>My component</h1>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from 'axios'

  export default {

    name: 'MyComponent',

    setup() {
      const baseUrl = 'your-api-base-url'

      const apiClient = axios.create({
         baseURL: baseUrl,
         withCredentials: false,
         headers: {
           Accept: 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         },
      })

      const getData = async() => {
         try {
            return await apiClient.get('/api-path', {}) // here i call my 
              api to get data you can call your function
         } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error)
         }
      }

      onMounted(() => {
        getData()
      })
    }
   }
 </script>
```

Comment: `return await apiClient.get({} + '/api-path')` will trigger an error because `{} + 'string'` is a NaN

Comment: just a typo, it's must be apiClient.get({}, '/api-path') first param is the payload and seconde is the api path

Comment: i think you need to reverse {} and '/api-path' get function accept path as first parameter and object for the second

Comment: Fixed to apiClient.get('/api-path', {})

Answer (score 5):

Mounted / BeforeMounted
Created

On Vuejs 3 you have onMounted
https://vuejs.org/api/